# How to load an iframe's content into visual basic?

Tags: html, vb.net, iframe

I have a web page which is simply a table with multiple bits of info inside. However, the source of that table is via an iframe that is in turn being driven by a json script fetching the info. I can ONLY see the source of the iframe if I right click some data in the iframe (in firefox) and select "view selection source".

So that's what I have coming in. What i want to do, is have a function in VB.net that pulls in this page, grabs the iframe, extracts the table from it, and then puts the values of the tables into some sort of array say "tablevalues(column,row)" that I can then process in VB.

I've seen numerous examples on how to pull in a simple html page, but extracting from the iframe is where I don't even know where to start. Any help appreciated

Comment: Are you talking about the web application itself pulling in its own iframe? Or do you want to have a separate program that makes the call to retrieve the iframe and parse the data out of it?

Comment: yes, the web app is pulling in data from a js at run time and inserting directly into the DOM, so that saying "view source" in the browser for example, doesn't show the table. yet if i select the table itself in the browser and right click, select "view selection source", i then see the table. confused as to what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

The website you provided had no iframes, however if this is the site you want to use, here is a way to go about it.  If I understand, you want to take the site, pull the data (scores) from the tables, and then process it (display it, do some calculations, etc):

So I checked the source code and did a GET request with Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) and saw that it was nice clean HTML:
[image: site source code]

For the example I just picked a div with those 1-2-3 scores - the class seemed to be `Whs(nw) D(tbc) Va(m) Fw(b) Fz(14px)` - not sure how reliable that is but it worked for this.

So there are multiple ways to parse this in VB.Net, since this is just an example, I went the easy route and used HtmlAgilityPack (https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) - here is a quick and dirty example just spitting those scores to a text box for now:
[image: code running]

And the code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Create a WebRequest object w/ our site
        Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://sports.yahoo.com/soccer/premier-league/scoreboard/")

        Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
        Using res As WebResponse = req.GetResponse() ' grab the HTML
            doc.Load(res.GetResponseStream()) ' load it into our HtmlDocument
        End Using

        ' Grab all the divs with a certain class
        Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='Whs(nw) D(tbc) Va(m) Fw(b) Fz(14px)']")
        If nodes IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each node As HtmlNode In nodes
                ' do the things
                TextBox1.AppendText(node.InnerText & Environment.NewLine)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe there's some confusion / you're going about this the wrong way.

An iframe is used to display html inside another html document (basically)
http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/IFrame-Inline-Frame

You're saying you want the HTML table content that the iframe produces.  Well naturally iframe prevents you from retrieving the inner html, unless on the same domain/origin (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Why not just do a GET request for the HTML that the iframe is displaying?  Or there is a script fetching info to display the table, use the data directly.

After you have the HTML you can use xElement or HtmlAgilityPack or similar to pull the Table HTML

---

**Update**

Posted new answer after getting more info from OP

Comment: it's possible i worded my question wrong, sorry. I know what an iframe is. This is not the problem. The issue is that what is GOING IN the iframe is fetched by a script, so that if i load up the html page and click "view source", I don't see the table and its contents. I only see the table if i inspect the DOM....  AFTER the page has loaded. This is what's confusing. If I set something up to inspect the html page, it sees no table at all.

Comment: @Rocks do you have some pictures you can supply of the DOM and what you're seeing?  I'm not sure it's possible to get the contents of an iframe from a web page, but if I see what's going on maybe I can understand better or whip something up to test real quick

Comment: ok well i can make it even simpler. here is the page i'm trying to pull the data from :   https://sports.yahoo.com/soccer/premier-league/scoreboard/   ..... if you simply look at the source you can't see any of the scores or the standings

Comment: @Rocks not sure if anything was attached